# GDPR & Firebase Realtime DataBase - Authentication and users identification: How to anonymize user data on firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, privacy

I'm implementing an Android app using Firebase (Authentication and Realtime Database).
Unfortunately, even if data can be encrypted in some way, I'm still looking for some methods to hide data shown in the Firebase Console (authentication tab).

In fact, in order to be compliant with the GDPR, the registered users should not be identifiable at all. Instead, I can read the list of the emails of all registered users ( currently, it's only me :-) since the app is still under development ).

How can I solve my problem?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I would like to know this as well. Can that tab be disabled?